# $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[104]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{7+\sqrt[5]{6+\sqrt[7]{x+17}}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[104]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{7+\sqrt[5]{6+\sqrt[7]{x+17}}}}$$

I need to take this limit. I suceed in proving that:

$$\sqrt[3]{7+\sqrt[5]{6+\sqrt[7]{x+17}}}>\sqrt[105]{x}$$

I tought this would help me, but in the end, I have:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{7+\sqrt[5]{6+\sqrt[7]{x+17}}}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt[105]{x}} \implies$$
$$\frac{\sqrt[104]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{7+\sqrt[5]{6+\sqrt[7]{x+17}}}}<\frac{\sqrt[104]{x}}{\sqrt[105]{x}} \implies$$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[104]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{7+\sqrt[5]{6+\sqrt[7]{x+17}}}}<\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[104]{x}}{\sqrt[105]{x}}<\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[10920]{x} = \infty$$

Wich does not help me. Is there a way to solve this by comparsion? It would be better to me. If not, is there a way to fator these roots out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x$ big enough we have $x+17<2^7x$, so $$\sqrt[7]{x}<\sqrt[7]{x+17}<2\sqrt[7]{x}.$$
Hence for $x$ big enough $6+\sqrt[7]{x+17}<6+2\sqrt[7]x<2^5\cdot \sqrt[7]{x} $ and then $$\sqrt[35]{x}<\sqrt[5]{6+\sqrt[7]{x+17}}<2\sqrt[35] x.$$
Hence for $x$ big enough $7+\sqrt[5]{6+\sqrt[7]{x+17}}<7+2\sqrt[35] x<2^3\sqrt[35]x$ and then 
$$ \sqrt[105]x<\sqrt[3]{7+\sqrt[5]{6+\sqrt[7]{x+17}}}<2\sqrt[105]x.$$
We conclude 
$$ \frac{\sqrt[104]x}{\sqrt[3]{7+\sqrt[5]{6+\sqrt[7]{x+17}}}}>\frac{\sqrt[104]x}{2\sqrt[105]x}=\frac12\sqrt[10920]x$$
for $x$ sufficiently big.

Answer (score 3):

We neglect the constant in face of $x$ at $\infty$ we have

$$\frac{\sqrt[104]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{7+\sqrt[5]{6+\sqrt[7]{x+17}}}}\sim_\infty\frac{x^{\frac1{104}}}{x^{\frac1{7\times 5\times 3}}}=x^{\frac1{104}-\frac1{105}}=x^{\frac1{104\times 105}}\xrightarrow{x\to\infty}\infty$$

**Edit** to prove the asymptotic equivalence:

$$\sqrt[3]{7+\sqrt[5]{6+\sqrt[7]{x+17}}}=\sqrt[3]{7+\sqrt[5]{6+x^{\frac1{17}}\sqrt[7]{1+\frac{17}x}}}=\sqrt[3]{7+x^{\frac1{17\times5}}\sqrt[5]{\frac6{x^{\frac1{17}}}+\sqrt[7]{1+\frac{17}x}}}\\=x^{\frac1{17\times5\times3}}\underbrace{\sqrt[3]{\frac7{x^{\frac1{17\times5}}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac6{x^{\frac1{17}}}+\sqrt[7]{1+\frac{17}x}}}}_{\xrightarrow{x\to\infty}1}\sim_\infty x^{\frac1{105}}$$

Comment: yep, when $x\to\infty$, then $\sqrt[3]{7+\sqrt[5]{6+\sqrt[7]{x+17}}}\to\sqrt[105]{x}$ but I can't justify this way, I must or: factor this, or prove by comparsion.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a broad hint: when $y\gt 7$, then $\sqrt[3]{7+y} \leq \sqrt[3]{y+y}=\sqrt[3]{2}\cdot\sqrt[3]{y}$.  Can you see how you can use this several times over to bound the denominator from *above* (rather than below) by a constant multiple of $\sqrt[105]{x}$ for sufficiently large $x$?

Comment: very good hint, I'm gonna try it!